# Would this question be too opinion based?

Tags: discussion

So I wanted to ask this fun question but i'm not sure if it would be too opinion based or maybe just not answerable.

> Lets say that some rogue nation, or alphabet government agency has a
>   0day they are actively exploiting out in the wild in order to spy on
>   targets.    The Attack has the following characteristics;
>
> - Lives in memory
> - Doesn't call out to any remote servers
> - Sits inactive (dormant)
>
> You being the security minded (paranoid) individual that you are. Have
>   a bad feeling in the back of your mind. In the event that said
>   malicious hackers successfully leverage this attack against you. With
>   the exception of buying/building a new system, a nuke from high orbit,
>   or a full system restore from a backup. How could you detect that you
>   have been hacked?
>
> I am looking for answers that cover a detection process that would be
>   OS agnostic. You are also allowed to infer a few things like "since
>   you have taken security measure X, Y and Z, this allows you to detect
>   the malware by doing ..."

Comment: IMO it's a very broad question because you seem to be asking "how to detect malware that's careful not to make noise" or "how to detect unknown threats". It strikes me more as a discussion topic than something that can be answered definitively.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Arminius - it's too broad as it stands. Of course you have options such as Tripwire to compare against known good code on disk, but these aren't useful for memory resident code. The real answer is that you would nuke and rebuild... same as you would in a corporate environment for most infections or suspected infections.